# Set nuget package source to use protocolVersion 3

Tags: .net-framework

Is there any way to specify protocolVersion for nuget *packageSource* entry via nuget CLI? I install nuget during Docker image build, and need to add custom package source and credentials, which is pretty straight forward with *nuget sources* and *nuget setapikey*, but I see no way to specify that source should use *protocolVersion* 3 via CLI. Without this option config file looks like

```
<add key="nuget.org" value="https://mynugetrepo.com/v3/index.json" />
```

while I need

```
<add key="nuget.org" value="https://mynugetrepo.com/v3/index.json" protocolVersion="3" />
```